# Can't ssh to a vps on another port than the default

Tags: linux, ssh

After changing the default port for ssh (by adding Port 443 or Port 44443 to the sshd conf file), I couldn't ssh to it from outside but could ssh to it locally.

`ufw status`  shows that OpenSSH is allowed from anywhere. What might be the issue here? the VPS is hosted by arubacloud. OS: ubuntu server 16.04

Comment: Are you sure `ufw` cares about what ports the process is connected to, and not just the ports in its configuration?

Comment: Can you connect to other services on these ports? (e.g: something simple like `netcat -l 443`)

Comment: @Attie tried that and it didn't work, I'm guessing it's an issue with the provider but I'm not sure how to check

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams my idea was to make sure that it isn't a firewall setting on my machine.